# How to get PaymentmethodID from Stripe using angular 12

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, angular12

I am working on payment gateway, i have successfully generated the stripetoken but in that Object there is no PaymentmethodID. on init i am calling invoke method and then on paymentclick i am calling makePayment

````
invokeStripe() {
  if(!window.document.getElementById('stripe-script')) {
    const script = window.document.createElement("script");
    script.id = "stripe-script";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js";
    script.onload = () => {
      this.paymentHandler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: this.stripeKey,
        locale: 'auto',
        token: function (stripeToken: any) {
          console.log(stripeToken)
          alert('Payment has been successfull!');
        }
      });
    }
       
    window.document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
}
makePayment(amount:any, id: any) {
  debugger;
  this.selectdAmount = amount;
  this.selectedID = id;
  const paymentHandler = (<any>window).paymentmethod.configure({

    
    key: this.stripeKey,
    locale: 'auto',
    token: (stripeToken: any) => {   
      console.log(stripeToken)
      this.stripeID = stripeToken.id; 
      this.BookNow(); 
    }
  });
 
  paymentHandler.open({
    name: 'Stripe',
    description: '2 widgets',
    amount: amount * 100
  }
  
  );
}```
 

can anybody giude me how can i get the paymentmethodID. i need full object to get this
````

Answer (score 0):

The product you are using has been actively deprecated by Stripe multiple years ago. You really shouldn't use it for a new integration, it's extremely limited and is not compatible with the majority of the new products and APIs. It's also impossible to get the "full object" client-side like this. This legacy integration used to create a card Token (deprecated too) and then you'd send it to your server to make a payment.

What you should do is move to the newer version of Stripe Checkout documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/how-checkout-works). It is a Stripe-hosted payment page that makes it a lot easier to collect payment method details (and not just card) and accept an end to end payment.

Alternatively you can build your own custom form using Stripe's UI component called PaymentElement which is covered in details in [this doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element).